# How to avoid v-text-field to emit input events?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to simulate the `v-model.lazy` for my `v-text-field` due to performance constraints.

I tried this:

```
<v-text-field :value="p.name" @change="v => p.name = v" :data-vv-name="'name'+p.id" v-validate="'required|max:255'" :error-messages="errors.collect('form'+p.id+'.'+'name'+p.id)" :counter="255" :label="$t('property.name')" required maxlength="255" :data-vv-as="' '" v-else></v-text-field>
```

But I keep getting all the keydowns and input emits, which is provoking a big lag:
[image]

If I use an input with a v-model.lazy it works as expected, but I'm not able to achieve the same thing using the v-text-field.

Should I use a prevent.default for those events?

Comment: Vue's modifiers don't work with custom component. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5743
I think you need to create a wrapper component for v-text-field and handle event manually

Comment: What would be the best way of doing that wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `data-vv-delay="1000"` and `:value="p.name" @change="v => p.name = v"` instead of `v-model` improved a lot the lag. This will delay de validation of the field.

The real solution would require `v-model.lazy` to work on Vuetify's `v-text-field`, but it is not the case yet.